# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Environment creation stuck in "Added instance [i-XXXXXXXXX] to your environment"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to deploy a Flask application using Elastic Beanstalk. This application needs to interact with an RDS database that lives inside of a VPC. So, I'm creating the app and the environment through the AWS Elastic Beanstalk console, and from there I'm specifying the custom VPC, the security group, the subnets, etc.

No matter why I try, or what inbound or outbound rules I add to the security group that I give to the environment, I always get this error after waiting for ~10-15 minutes (which results in a health status of `No Data`):

```
The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time (they might still finish eventually on their own): [i-XXXXXXXXXXX].
```

What I understand is that, for some reason, EC2 cannot communicate with the EB environment. I have tried all of the solutions that I have found in here, and also on re:Post and Stack Exchange (like adding a NAT Gateway, verifying that I have a public IP address on the EC2 instance, re-starting the EC2 instances manually, [adding NTP inbound and outbound rules to the security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html)), but nothing has helped.

What am I missing? Obviously, there is something that I'm not considering here.

Comment: try to deploy to more expensive instance.  Timeouts usually happen because it freezes.

Comment: When checking the EC2 instance from the EC2 dashboard, it appears as running. The thing is that, for some reason, EB does not registers it as running.

Comment: Is your app in /var/app/current/ ? If not you should look at the deployment logs. Honestly, without looking at the logs that shows the error we can't know the exact reason.